# Changing Exposed Filter Label in Views

Tags: 7, views

I have a view in Drupal 7 site that needs some editing. In particular, there are some exposed filters on that page that require their labels to be changed. How can I do that?

I cannot seem to find where to do that. From my understanding, the filters are innate to the Views module.

Comment: What do you mean 'change' the label? Exposed filters can have their labels changed from the UI of the View that exposes them. See: http://www.bryanbraun.com/2013/08/06/drupal-tutorials-exposed-filters-with-views

Comment: I mean literally the label that is seen by the user when the view is rendered. I have already seen this page. However, when I click on "Edit Exposed Filters" I do not see a place there that allows for the label to be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Kevin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/57/kevin) already suggested.

In the following image, Please, see the red circle. From that input text area you can change the Label. Are you looking something else?

[image]